# useing Database Documenter tool via vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

there is a UI tool in ms access named 'Database Documenter'

is there's a way to use it vba instead of UI ?

i am looking for do this steps separately for each object and each day.

any other solution ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this daily? Normally, the things that can't be accessed by VBA are those things that **shouldn't** be done through VBA......

Comment: i am search for a solution for usually logging of all changes, i want to output all this data to git directory, and identify changes

Comment: You may want to look at `SaveAsText` to create your own documenter that you can then run and import the files it produces.

Comment: thanks  'Applecore'. it's a good idea..

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. However, under menu *database tools* you'll find *Object dependencies*.

Also, **FMS** offers the [Total Access Analyzer](https://fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/BestPractices.html).